# Reusing tables for purposes other than the intended

Tags: database, reusability

We need to implement some new functionality for some clients. The functionality is essentially an EULA accept interface for the users. Users will open our app, will be presented with the corresponding EULA (varies from client to client). It needs to be able to store different versions of the EULA for the same client, and it also needs to store which users have accepted which version of the EULA. If a new version is saved, it will be presented to the users the next time they log in.

I've written a document suggesting to add two tables, `EULAs` and `UserAcceptedEULA`. That will allow us to store different EULAs and keep track of the accepted ones, current and previous ones.

My problem comes with how some people at the company want to do the implementation. They suggest to use a table `ConstantGroups` (which contains `ConstantGroupID`, `Timestamp`, `ClientID` and `Name`) that we use for grouping constants with their values that are stored in another table, e.g.: `ConstantGroup` would be `Quality`, and the values would be `High`, `Medium`, `Low`.

To me this is a horrible, incredibly wrong way to do it. They're suggesting it because we already have an endpoint where you pass the `ClientID` and you get back a string, so it "does what we need".

I wrote the document explaining the whole solution, covering DB changes, APIs needed and UI modifications, but they still don't want to accept it because they thing their way will save us time.

How do I make them understand how horribly wrong they are?

Comment: Does ConstantGroups give you back the text of the EULA? If so, where do you store the acceptance of the EULA?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt in a meta tag associated with the constants.

Answer (score 2):

This depends somewhat on your assumptions about "good" design.

Many software folk have adopted the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) as being "good" (I am one of them). While the original thinking is about object oriented design, I think many apply to databases too.

The first element of that is "Single responsibility". A table should do one thing, and one thing only. Your colleagues are trying to get a single entity to manage different concepts; the Constants table suddenly is responsible for "constants" and "EULA acceptance".

That leads to "Open to extension, closed to change" - if you need to change the implementation of "constants" or "EULAs", you have to untangle the other. So any time you (might) save now will cost you later.

The second principle I like (especially in database design) is the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Imagine a new developer joining the team, and having to figure out how EULAs work. They would naturally look for some kind of "EULA" and "Acceptance" tables, and would be astonished to learn that actually, this is managed in a thing called "constants". Any time you save now will be repaid by onboarding new people (or indeed, reminding yourself in 2 years time when you have to fix a bug).